# Tab Order With Selected Area

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

During Design Time of a Windows Form there are a lot of controls to assign their Tab Order with VS Tab Order Button automatically (by clicking each control sequantially).

Is there a way to select a Specific Area in form (contaning limited count of controls to be tab ordered).

Otherwise Tab Order button selects all controls in the form (Labels have no Tab Order although) and it is very diffucult to see clearly related control to click.

Comment: No the designer doesn't have such feature, however, if you have such requirement, you can create some user controls and then setup the tab indexes in each user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the designer doesn't have such feature, however, if you have such requirement, you can create some user controls and then setup the tab indexes in designer of each user control.

This way you decide about the tab indexes of the user control in the designer of the user control and the tab indexes of the user controls will be part of the user control definition and will be reused in different forms.

Also since the user control is a container control, at the designer of the form, you need to just specify the tab index for the user controls. Also you will see less controls to assign tab index.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why MS, while allowing developer to change some properties (fonts etc) of selected controls in a specific area, not let developer do same with TAB Index. Thanks for answer but it does not eliminate my job load...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is what it is. The answer to your question '*Is there a way to select a Specific Area in form (contaning limited count of controls to be tab ordered)*' is 'No'. But in addition to the 'No', the answer shares an example of power of user controls to reuse tab orders. Another approach is relying on containers. First set containers tab order, then set tab order of chikd controls per container.